# Spring + RMI + transactions + weblogic

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactions, weblogic

We have developed two web services (A,B) with **Spring 3, Hibernate 4 & JPA**.

Inside a method of service A we need to call to an method of service B. The access is through `RMI`.
The problem is that the two of them need to be in the same transaction. I think we followed all of the rules dealing with transactions but we cannot rollback the method in service B when service A crashes after method in service B is called.

If an `exception` is thrown in service A after service B is called the data that service A has changed is rolled back, but not the data changed by service B. It seems that the transaction is ***renewed*** in service B and not included in that created in service B.

We use a `jndi` datasource created in `weblogic`.
The transactional methods are annotated with:

```
*@Transactional( readOnly = false, isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, 
                rollbackFor=Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED )*
```

Here is my configuration dealing with transactions:

`spring-server.xml` (the only data that differs from service to service is the persistence-unit name):

```
    *<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
         <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SAPOY/SANOT" />
         </bean>
    <bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true"/>
        <property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
<!-- Servicio SAPOY.SANOT -->
    <bean id="sanot" class="com.sems.sapoy.sanot.services.impl.Sanot">
        <property name="sanotBiz" ref="sanotBiz" />
   </bean>*
```

`persistence.xml` (the only data that differs from service to service is the persistence-unit name):

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SAPOY/SANOT" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>Unidad de Persistencia del modulo SANOT</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/xaDS</jta-data-source>


        <properties>
            <!-- 
            ################################################################
            HIBERNATE
            ################################################################ 
            -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.autoReconnect" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.autoReconnectForPools" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory" />

            <!-- 
            ################################################################
            CONNECTION
            ################################################################ 
            -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <!-- 
            ################################################################
            CACHE
            ################################################################ 
            -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>*
```

Comment: Have you tried with the custom `WebLogicJtaTransactionManager` instead of the plain `JtaTransactionManager` also how are you calling the RMI are you using Spring's RMI Remoting or your own RMI generated stubs? Also see [this forum post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/128397-transaction-management-over-rmi-weblogic).

Comment: I tried with WebLogicJtaTransactionManager but obtained the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataSource/TransactionManager configurations are just fine, the only problem is that you call your other service through RMI.

The global transactions must be coordinated from the same running Thread that may enlist one or more Resources (JDBC connections/JMS queues), but it cannot span over multiple threads.

The moment you call a RMI method, that call is going to be served by a RMI server which assigns a working thread to service your RMI request. Even if that method is `@Transactional` the transaction will be defined at the RMI working thread boundary.

Try removing the RMI call and it will work. Implementing it over multiple servers is not a trivial thing to do. You'd probably have to use something like the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), so that the Service A can call Service B to undo when Service A fails to commit. Like I said, this is not as trivial as a global XA transaction. It requires careful design and it may lead to inconsistencies to due undos happening after other transaction already used the already committed changes.

For that you need [WS-Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Transaction) and a [Application server to support it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/transaction.htm). By itself JTA manages global transactions on a Thread basis. To span transactions over multiple Threads you need a higher-level protocol like WS-Transactions.

Comment: I understand what you explained but the what is a distributed transaction if I cannot join two different service calls?

Comment: In a global transaction you can join two different service call as long as they are issued from the same Thread.

Comment: I don't understand last comment, how can I call to different web services from the same thread?

Comment: For that you need [WS-Transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Transaction) and a [Application server to support it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13734/transaction.htm). By itself JTA manages global transactions on a Thread basis. To span transactions over multiple Threads you need a higher-level protocol like WS-Transactions.